# Objective C: How to make a subclass of UIControl react like a button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, button, uicontrol

I have a subclass of UIControl and within the control I am adding a UILabel and UIImageview to constitute my button.

As a subclass of UIControl, I believe I am unable to utilize the method '[doSomethingButton setBackgroundImage:stretchableButtonImagePressed
forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]' to set the the UIControl to a different image when clicker

How can I mimic a button's reaction to a user's touch i.e. (UIControlStateHighlighted)

Comment: I have to ask.  Is there a reason you can't just subclass `UIButton`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, the setBackgroundImage:ForState method is a method for UIButton.
The easiest to achieve your goal would be to update the imageView && label states in the action selector of your UIControl.

Comment: any way I can set the new image and then after say 2 seconds let it change back to the original image automatically? So it looks like the effect on pressing on a button

Answer (score 1):

A subclass do all the works which original works. You can directly set the UIImage for highlighted state to your subclassed control.

Comment: thanks for your response. Can I check what method can I use to do this? I was not able to use the method '[doSomethingButton setBackgroundImage:stretchableButtonImagePressed forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]' for my case as I did not add a UIButton to my subclass of UIControl. All I had as subviews of the UIControl are a uilabel and a uiimageview